# Create Thread to run Class function with parameters

Tags: c#

I would like to know how to create a thread for a method of a class with multiple parameters.

Below is the method of the class that I would like to convert to thread.

```
Display dp1 = new Display();
dp1.DisplayOnDataGridView(DroneList, gmap, TCP_ListBox1, UDP_ListBox1, WhitelistListBox, ButtonStartScan, 20, true);
```

As I am running this on a timer, it will consume a lot of memory and also affect the UI smoothness. So, I plan to replace the timer with thread in order for the UI to work smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Task.Run() for this if your code is thread safe.

Example:

```
var t = Task.Run(() => {
                 //your code here
                });
t.Wait(); //this halts the application until your code is finished. This line is not neccessary
```

Comment: I tried using this but the method is not executing.

Comment: Have you put your code where it says "// your code here" ? If so, maybe you are trying something that has no place in a seperate thread. If the Task fails, you can examine the `t` variable for its result.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update a ListBox on a thread other than the it belongs.

If you need to add/update multiple lines in a ListBox, you should use the [BeginUpdate/EndUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.beginupdate?view=netframework-4.8)
If you need to load/process data, you can do that on a thread. But I would still use a timer to refresh the data. *(number of messages per second with UDP can get quite high.)*

Comment: Hi, I am using timer now to load the data into DataGridView. However, this will consume a lot of memory and also make the UI very lag.

Comment: @max Adding the data to the DataGridView, How many rows are you adding? Are they all visibile? For the DataGridView is a similar method. Use the `dataGridView.SuspendDrawing` and `dataGridView.ResumeDrawing()`

Comment: The DataGridView will always be updated and they are all visible. As the DataGridView is showing near to almost live data, I would not be able to use SuspendDrawing and ResumeDrawing.

Comment: The suspendDrawing is only when updating the data. So it won't redraw on each row update. so...   `suspendDrawing -> update row1 -> update row2 -> update row3 -> resumeDrawing`